# How to run application on boot with privileges?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-task-scheduler

I've an installer that should deploy an application that need to run on each boot of the system with privileges. The installer requires privileges to run.

I've made a solution that runs an application with SYSTEM account privileges by using Windows Scheduled Tasks. Unfortunately, this solution is not working on **Windows XP** due to a [known issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/223375/cannot-configure-scheduled-tasks-to-use-system-account).

Any ideas how to run my application on boot with privileges?

Comment: It should work in any supported Windows version, 7, 8.x or 10.

Comment: Thanks for down voting. it **should** work... Did you tried it on Windows XP? Did you read my question in details?

Comment: Yes, I certainly did... XP in 2017, hence the suggestion to use a **supported** Windows version which incidentally neither have that problem you mentioned and receive security updates that avoid them being used for criminal activities that can cause harm somewhere. Please be socially responsible.

Comment: Do you understand that Windows XP is still used by customers? Do you also understand that this is not my fault that customers are using Windows XP and I need to provide them a solution? And finally, If you really had tested it on Windows XP you would saw that it is failing to run as described in **official** microsoft article.

Comment: what about using Registry? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a user for this specific task, so it has needed privileges. Then test on how this user will execute needed package.

Comment: Thanks, we decided to convert our application into the service and make it auto-startable.